# Error in connecting to PostgreSQL database using data inserted from android application through PHP

Tags: java, php, android, postgresql-9.1

My current android application allows user to key in chat room name where I'll be utilizing the name stored as the database name.  Hence the name stored will be used to connect to the database using PHP web service. I understand that there're some solutions which is editing the pg_ident.conf file, allowing www-data to be recognized as one of the users to access the database. However, I'm hoping to have a better solution. Thanks in advance for the help given.

This is the error message I got

> Warning: pg_connect() [function.pg-connect]: Unable to connect to
>   PostgreSQL server: FATAL: role "www-data" does not exist.

PHP code (blabla.php)

```
<?php
 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "bbcc";
 $db=$_POST['name'];
 $passwd = "abc";

 $con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$passwd") or die ("Could not connect to server\n" . pg_last_error());
?>
```

Java code snippet

```
   private void valid() { 

        String room = "abcd";
        try{
             HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
             HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 20 * 1000);
             HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30 * 1000);
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://111.11.111.000/script/blabla.php");
             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();    
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", room));
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

Comment: Did you create an user www-data in Postgres? Perhaps not. Honestly: the desire to have a database per room or whatever indicates a serious misunderstanding of how relational databases are used! Usually you have ONE database per application, one or more TABLES to hold your model, and your room would be a single ROW in a table. Do yourself a favor and read some tutorial on databases, it will pay off 10 times!

Comment: Gyro, thanks for the advice, I never thought of changing www-data to one of the users in Postgres, as it's totally out of the way, have made some changes in the database structure, thanks for pointing the way out, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

check this settings pg_hba.conf

This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:

```
local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
host       DATABASE  USER  CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
hostssl    DATABASE  USER  CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
```